# Convert RGB color to saturated color and transparency

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, transparency, saturation

I have a logo with several colors at the edge that look OK with a white background. When I overlay it on a background of another color, the edge is not smooth and looks off. Therefore, I would like to convert the two edge colors to a transparency of a saturated color, so they blend nicely in any background.

Following [How can I desaturate a color in illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66232/how-can-i-desaturate-a-color-in-illustrator/66233), on Illustrator CS5, I set the opacity of the two colors to the value of saturation, and set saturation to 100%. The result has transparency but looks different on a white background: the outermost yellow is paler and the second outermost salmon is more pink.

[image: Original logo, solid colors]

[image: Logo with transparency of saturated colors]

How can I convert an RGB color to transparency of a saturated color?

### update

Here are the same two files on a transparent background: the solid colors:

[image: solid colors on transparent background]

and the transparency of saturated colors:

[image: transparency of saturated color on transparent background]

And what I am looking for is a nice blend with a background color like yellow, which is not smooth with the original solid colors:

[image: solid colors on yellow background]

and is smooth with transparency of saturated colors:

[image: transparency of saturated colors on yellow background]

Comment: As neither example has been saved with transparency, it's not too easy to see quite what you mean. Transparency has no colour, it's a simple alpha value - how much you can see through it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I updated the question, please tell me if it's clear now.

Comment: If this is in **Illustrator** and thus **vector** ... merely select the objects and delete them. If it's all vector, you are overcomplicating things. `Select > Same > Fill Color` then hit Delete. (sidebar, if this is *really* a "logo"... I, personally, think you could refine the drawing *considerably* for optimum usage. Tracing is fine as a *starting point* but for "logos" it is exceptionally rare an image trace is adequate, let alone usable.)

Comment: @Scott Yes, this is a vector. I prefer not to delete the objects but to make them partly transparent. Indeed, it's not a logo, rather an avatar, and I did use tracing to make it.